# WCF channelfactory exception

Tags: c#, wcf

I try to set up an connection to another pc, but then i try to create a channel i get an exception, i have no idea what is cousing this problem, becouse to some pc's it works

this is the code:

```
var ep = "net.tcp://" + targetIpAddress + ":9985/IBC";
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
binding.ListenBacklog = 2000;
binding.MaxConnections = 2000;
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1048576;
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

ChannelFactory<IBlissRequest> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<IBlissRequest>(binding, new EndpointAddress(ep)); //here i get the exception
client.ChannelFactory = pipeFactory;
```

Exception: `Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.`

Full stack trace:

```
bij System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) 
bij System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
bij System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.GetKnownTypes(Object[] knownTypeAttributes, ICustomAttributeProvider provider) 
bij System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.UpdateOperationsWithInterfaceAttributes(ContractDescription contractDesc, ContractReflectionInfo reflectionInfo) 
bij System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type contractType, Type serviceType, Object serviceImplementation) 
bij System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateDescription() 
bij System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address) 
bij System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) 
bij System21.Network.InterBlissCommunication.InternalMethodInvoke(String targetIpAddress, Boolean Async, Object state, CallbackMethod callbackMethod, BpuMethod MethodName, Object[] Parameters)
```

This code is accesed by multiple threads, when i put a lock around it the problem seems to be solved (the problem might be that it trys to make a duplicate connection with the same ipAddress)

Comment: whats your full stack trace?

Comment: I posted it in the question for you